# How do I add HTML tags and links in QnA-maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I have tried the suggestions provided for other similar questions but they didn't work.
here 2 example:
1) Link:  [name of your link](https://url.com) is changed by QnAMaker during the save and train step in name of your link](https://url.com)) and it is diplayed in the test feature
name of your link](https://url.com))
2) <b> bold text </b> is not changed in bold and the same thing happens with the escaped html

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider markdown? You examples are supported.
[Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) to help you on you way.